# Google Apps Script Combo chart duplicates same values on x-axis

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

When I use a Combo Chart with serie type:Line the values on the x-axis get duplicated. For example the data range used for the display:

> ```
>     
>     X       Y
>     31      0
>     31      0,1
>     32,6    0,1
>     32,6    0
>     32,6    0,35
>     34,2    0,35
>     34,2    0
>     34,2    0,1
>     35,8    0,1
>     35,8    0
>     35,8    0,3
>     37,4    0,3
>     37,4    0
>     37,4    0,1
>     39      0,1
>     39      0
>     40,6    0
>     42,2    0
>     43,8    0
>     45,4    0
>     45,4    0,05
>     47      0,05
>     47      0
> ```

In above the Combo Chart with serie type:

Line drawn:

[image]
All values for X on x-axis are duplicate. The scatter chart draws 2 points for each X values.
I want to show single x-axis value with different y-axis values.

I want the combo chart output should be like :
[image]

**In this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hgptynoUuuPDg5SvTH3l68mt7eWvX5DOdvkvK_rde4Q/edit#gid=907746395, you can launch the script "unitDisplaySerie" in script editor to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: How do you create this graph with sheets? Also the first one doesn't have duplicates, it's just displaying all values (you have 2 x values of 31, for example)

Comment: I'm displayed this combo chart using Google app script. Why the value on X-axis are not merged (like in second chart) ? @RafaGuillermo

Comment: What is the second graph how did you draw it?

Comment: I draw the second graph by changing manually the type of chart in Google spreadsheet chart editor by modifiy  Combo Chart with serie type to Line chart. @RafaGuillermo

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: In this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hgptynoUuuPDg5SvTH3l68mt7eWvX5DOdvkvK_rde4Q/edit#gid=907746395, you can launch the script "unitDisplaySerie" in script editor to reproduce the problem. @RafaGuillermo

Comment: Because of the type of chart you're using, as long as you hav duplicate X values the combo chart will display all of them. If you want to not have then you'll have to either just use a line chart or exclude the rows from your data set that you don't want.

Comment: [Combo charts are designed to display multiple types of data at once](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142593#combo_chart) and so don't ignore duplicate values for x/y

Comment: Thank you for your answers @RafaGuillermo. 
But I find it strange that there is different behavior between the combo chart created by app script and that by Google visualization ! I have create an example for Google Visualization on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ue8y0s45/2/) and the result is like expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

After doing some testing with both the Sheets method of creating charts and the Visualization API it seems that this is inconsistent and probably unintended. I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Inconsistent behaviour between Vizualization API and Apps Script when creating new Combo chart](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154577140)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.